# iOS 7 UITableView inside a popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableView which has some custom styling. This table view appears in two places in the app, one of which is inside a UIPopoverController. However when the tableview is inside the popover it takes on the default tableview styling as stated in the [UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/ContentViews.html) under "Popover".

The problem I have is that there appears to be nowhere to change this behaviour. Regardless of where I try and modify properties of the tableview the view inside the popover doesn't change.

Anyone dealt with this issue before or have any ideas?

Here is the init method of LibraryProductView where I create the table view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.sectionOrdering = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:LIBRARY_PRODUCT_SECTION_DESCRIPTION],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:LIBRARY_PRODUCT_SECTION_DOCUMENTS],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:LIBRARY_PRODUCT_SECTION_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:LIBRARY_PRODUCT_SECTION_RELATED_PRODUCTS],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:LIBRARY_PRODUCT_SECTION_RELATED_DOCUMENTS], nil];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 10, 0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

        [self addSubview:self.tableView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is where the containing view (LibraryProductView) is added to the popover:

```
- (IBAction)didTouchInformationButton:(id)sender
{
    if (_infoPopover != nil && _infoPopover.isPopoverVisible)
    {
        [_infoPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }

    CGSize preferredSize = CGSizeMake(600.0f, 500.0f);

    LibraryProductViewController* productController = [[[LibraryProductViewController alloc] initWithPreferredSize:preferredSize] autorelease];
    productController.filterByMyCompany = NO;
    productController.product = _activityInput.product;

    UINavigationController* nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:productController] autorelease];
    nav.title = _activityInput.product.name;

    RELEASE(_infoPopover);
    _infoPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
    _infoPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height + 46);
    [_infoPopover presentPopoverFromRect:_infoButton.frame inView:_infoButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

The LibraryProductView is created within viewDidLoad method of LibraryProductViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.libraryProductView = [[LibraryProductView alloc] initWithFrame:(usingPreferredSize ? CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height) : self.view.bounds)];
    self.libraryProductView.dataSource = self;
    self.libraryProductView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.libraryProductView];
}
```

Comment: Update some code here, you have implemented.

Comment: You should consider that you have an error in your code. So you should show it to us.

Comment: I have added some code. Also why is this question marked as "off topic" when it is entirely on topic since it is "a specific programming problem"? One of the properties that fails to get set is `separatorColor`.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

To set properties for the TableView you might do so in

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redcolor]];
    [tableView setSeparatorColor: [UIColor blueColor]];

    return 1;
}
```

This, of course, assumes you have set UITableViewDataSource in your .h file